# Как в этом блоке скрыть кнопки после нажатия?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как в этом блоке скрыть кнопки после нажатия одной из них?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('CV', callback_data='CV')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Vacancy', callback_data='Vacancy')

    markup.add(item1)
    markup.add(item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "What would you like to create:", reply_markup=markup) 


обработчик


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['CV', 'Vacancy'])
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'CV':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Development (Frontend, backend, full-stack, mobile, web, gamedev)',callback_data='Development')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Testing ',callback_data='Testing')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('DevOps/Admin',callback_data='DevOps')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Data Science ',callback_data='Data Science')
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('TOP Management (CTO, CIO, Director) ',callback_data='TOP')
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Support, Helpdesk',callback_data='Support')
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PR, marketing, advertising',callback_data='PR')
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Project/Product manager,HR',callback_data='Project')
                item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Design',callback_data='Design')



                markup.add(item1)
                markup.add(item2,item3,item4)
                markup.add(item5)
                markup.add(item6,item7,item9)
                markup.add(item8,item8)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "CV - Choose a specialization :", reply_markup=markup)

            elif call.data == 'Vacancy':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('less then $1000', callback_data='less')

                markup.add(item1)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Your budget($):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="What would you like to create")
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Comment: У Вас обработчик для этих кнопок есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решений два: либо при отправке сообщения не передавать клавиатуру вовсе (reply_markup), либо удалять сообщение, на которое кликнули, целиком.